# How to get the old Test Class UI back? Or possible workarounds with the new UI?

Tags: administration, generics

Is there anyone else who is sorely missing the old test class UI where it shows the entire list of Apex classes covered by running one test class? Another good feature of the old UI was that you could simply hit F5 to re-run the test class. Is there any way to get the old UI back?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but I believe the summer release will already include some improvements to the new test execution page.

Comment: @Sdry, thank you for your reply. Yes, your guess was right, I am still on Spring '13.

Comment: You could erase your whole code coverage data and run just this 1 test. Not too useful but it's an option :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### For Spring '13 (when the question was posted):

Well, the new developer console is our friend :)

- Switch to the <kbd>Tests</kbd> tab and you will see the **Overall code coverage**
- To run the test again just click on <kbd>Re-Run</kbd> button:

[image]

---

### For Summer '13:

To run the test again just select <kbd>Test</kbd> → <kbd>Re-Run</kbd> from the menu bar:

[image]

Switch to the <kbd>Tests</kbd> tab and you will see the **Overall code coverage**:

[image]